# Angularjs + Spotify Views API (1.0): DOM Error Exception 8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, spotify

I'm writing a very simple AngularJS directive to communicate with Spotify API (1.0).
I've this custom directive that should create a Spotify `List` View (reference here: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/list-list.html).

Here's the Angular directive:

```
angular.module('spotify.view.list', [])
  .directive('spList', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    var rootScope = $rootScope
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      replace: true,
      link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
        var fn = attrs['for'], list = null, playlist
        attrs.$observe('uri', function(newval, oldval) {
          require(['$views/list#List', '$api/models'], function(List, models) {   
            if(newval != oldval && list == null) {
              playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI(attrs.uri)
              list = List.forPlaylist(playlist, {
                layout: 'default',
                header: attrs.header||'no',
                fields: attrs.fields.split(','),
                height: attrs.height||'fixed',
                numItems: 10
              })

              var targetEl = document.getElementById(attrs.node)
              targetEl.appendChild(list.node)
              list.init()

            }
          })
        })

      }
    }
  })
```

and this is how I call the directive inside an Angular template:

```
    <div class="playlist-tracklist" id="sp-playlist"></div>

    <sp-list
        for="playlist"
        fields="track,artist"
        header="yes"
        type="tracks"
        layout="default"
        uri="{{playlist.playlist_uri}}"
        node="sp-playlist">
    </sp-list>
```

The problem here is that I randomly get a `DOMException Error`:

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

This's totally random: sometimes it works and I get back a Spotify List, sometimes it won't and console doesn't give me any other debugging info.

I cannot find any way to reproduce the Exception, but I guess it's something have to do with the `targetEl`.

I'd love to know why trying to append the List to an abritrary HTML element fails, even if this HTML element exists for sure, and what is the cause of Exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be re-inserting script tags each time you call require; the library does not do any caching of those modules. I believe the DOM exception happens when a script tag times out for some reason (server does not return a 304 or 200). Try loading the modules outside of your angular directive and also can you try and verify if it is actually loading script tags more than necessary?

Comment: Tnx for reply. How would you load modules outside Angular directive? I mean, how do I reference `List` in my directive?

Comment: I temporarily solved the issue by wrapping the `list` initialization and insertion in the DOM in a `$timeout`. Anyway I'd like to understand why it fails. Maybe the function is invoked before template rendering? Again, regarding your answer, do you have any idea on how to verity "if it is actually loading script tags more than necessary"?

Comment: I have created a few [AngularJS directives to be used within Spotify Apps](https://github.com/JMPerez/angularjs-spotify-apps-directives) and I haven't had that DOMException issue. It is true that due to the fact that AngularJS doesn't support async modules, you need to add the `require` function in every directive. If you suspect your directive may be loading several times for each tag, print out a message in the console showing the element's contents before injecting the `Image` to see what is in there.